# Intersection number for 4 manifold with boundary

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology

Let $X$ be a closed oriented smooth $4$-manifold. Suppose there is an embedding $\Sigma\to X$, it is known that the self-intersection number satisfies  $[\Sigma]\cdot [\Sigma]=\pm\int_\Sigma c_1(N)$, where $N$ is the normal bundle to $\Sigma$.

**Question**

When $X$ is compact with boundary, and the embedding  $\Sigma\to X$ is away from the boundary, does the intersection formula "$[\Sigma]\cdot [\Sigma]=\pm\int_\Sigma c_1(N)$" still holds, or we need some condition for the boundary, e.g. homology sphere?

Any reference or hint is welcome.

Comment: Assuming $\Sigma$ is closed, yes. This just uses deRham representatives that are compactly supported near the surface. If $\Sigma$ has boundary, the (absolute) self-intersection number does not make sense, as you'd expect because of "runaway intersection points".